# Swipe Detection and input handling in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am working on a game with **LibGDX**, and my stage is set as input processor:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Everything works fine, but now I want to act on swipe *(left and right)*. I see some samples which suggest extending GestureListener, and setting it as input processor. But if I do that, then my stage can no longer be input processor as well. So, how do I get both touch and swipe events?

Comment: Probably you just need a `ScrollPane`, that thing will indeed scroll on swipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to have more than one InputProcessor, you have to use an [InputMultiplexer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputmultiplexer) which chains multiple InputProcessors. For example:

```
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
multiplexer.addProcessor(myGestureListener);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

This way Libgdx will listen to both stage's and GestureListener's events.